# Hosting supports .net4 but not mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, web-hosting

I have been conmunicating with my current hosting provider. They say they support .net4 but not MVC3.

I understand that you may need to install mvc3 on the server from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Is there anyway to avoid this? Can I just include the MVC dlls when building?

Unfortunately I cannot test this with them since I am hosting as .net2. Before I go setting up a vmare I wanted to ask here first.

i just need to be certain that moving away from my current hosting a firm decision.

(I am not looking for hosting suggestions or comapany name dropping)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you only need to include the MVC 3 dlls in the bin folder of your application when you deploy it.

As long as the hosting provider supports ASP .NET 4.0 you'll be ok

Here is a [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx) from someone who knows what they're talking about

Comment: Did this two days ago with a Server 2003 machine running IIS6. Deployed an MVC3 application to it with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

Yea, all you need to do is Bin deploy the MVC dll and you should be good to go.  Here is a great blog on the subject.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx